# Followed question comments have incorrect formatting, in the network profile Inbox page

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, stackexchange.com, global-inbox

Looking through my inbox page in the [Stack Exchange network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/18074340/ollie), I keep seeing that some of the comments I've received on a followed post aren't showing the links in them, which you can see at the end:

[image: Link shows as plain markdown]

[The actual comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1172730?noredirect=1) has three links at the end, which show up as hyperlinks.  But the inbox note just shows the raw markdown.  Can we fix that?